# Simplify an equation by giving some variable a value in R

Tags: r, math, equation

I want to simplify the equation below, and at the same time, varies the value of b

```
b*(b*((1-b)*x) + (1-b)*y) + (1-b)*z
```

So, if I give b = 0.9,

```
b <- 0.9
# the answer will be:
0.081x + 0.09y + 0.1z
```

The reason is I want to see how different values of b, will impact the weights/coefficients of x, y, and z.

I have no idea how to do this, or if it even possible in R.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for symbolic maths -- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rSymPy/index.html ?

Comment: @markus the output I'm looking is exactly this 0.081x + 0.09y + 0.1z. Probably I'm going to plot those coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may try `Reduce` like below

```
Reduce(function(u, v) b * u + v, (1 - b) * c(x, y, z))
```

and you will see

```
> b <- 0.9

> x <- 1e3

> y <- 1e2

> z <- 1e1

> Reduce(function(u, v) b * u + v, (1 - b) * c(x, y, z))
[1] 91
```

---

If you want to see the coefficients of `x`, `y` and `z`, you can use

```
> f <- function(b) (1 - b) * b^((3:1) - 1)

> f(0.9)
[1] 0.081 0.090 0.100
```

and the sum of weighted `x`, `y`, and `z` can be written as

```
s = sum(f(0.9)*c(x,y,z))
```